# How can I accept multiple multipart files in my Spring MVC REST controller

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC REST controller that accepts a multipart file, as follows:

```
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@RequestMapping(value = "/save-comment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addComment(@FormDataParam("jsonData") String jsonData, @FormDataParam("file") MultipartFile file, ModelMap model)
{
    //My Logic to save file and data
}
```

I use Jersey REST client in my application. The above code works fine for me. Now I am trying to POST multiple files to my REST controller.

I tried to change `@FormDataParam("file") MultipartFile file` to `@FormDataParam("file") MultipartFile[] file`  but it is not working for me. How can I pass multiple files at a time to a REST controller?

The exception I get is: nested exception is

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [[Lorg.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: [Lorg.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;.<init>()] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: [Lorg.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;.<init>()
```

Answer (score 2):

Multiple File Upload concept , we can handle by using MultipartFile Interface.

Package:
org.springframework.web.mutipart
public interface MutipartFile

MutipartFile is an interface, Commonly Client will send or upload a file , it will be sent to server as in the form of mutipart request.

We will catch that mutipart request by using MutipartFile Concept. This MutipartFile Interface have number of method , those methods are used to get information of that file and if you want to do any copy or moving of a file also we can perform by one of the method called transferTo(“destinationPath”) ;

for better understanding purpose just visit https://walkintoknow.blogspot.com/2018/05/multiple-files-upload-concept-handling.html

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/multipleFilesUpload" , method=RequestMethod.POST, 
consumes="multipart/form-data", produces="application/json")  
public ResponseEntity<?> mutipleFileUpload(HttpServletRequest req, 

@RequestParam(value="file" , required = false) MultipartFile[] files) throws IOException{

for (MultipartFile file : files) {
 File f= new File(getPath()+createFolderInDesc("/appFiles /GSTC/mutipleUpload/"),file.getOriginalFilename());
   try {
        file.transferTo(f); //Transfer or Saving in local memory 
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    return null;
}
```

if it helps please promote.

Comment: I am trying to post the multipart file to my REST Controller using jersey client. How do I do that? Can you help me with that

Comment: you can post multipart file to Rest Controller by configuring small steps , use this link for Multipart File upload using Jersey Frame work [link](https://walkintoknow.blogspot.com/2018/06/mutipart-file-upload-using-jersey.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just typecast normal http request to multipart request like below :

```
try {
            MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) httpServletRequest;
            List<MultipartFile> multipartFileList = multipartRequest
                    .getFiles("images");

            if (null != multipartFileList && !multipartFileList.isEmpty()) {

                for (MultipartFile file : multipartFileList) {
                    String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename().trim();
                    if (file.getBytes().length > 0) {
                        // logic goes gere
                    }

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```