# Spring controller cannot read image file from multipart/form-data post request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-rest, spring-web

I am trying to upload a form that has both text fields and an image using multipart/form-data as the content type. When i do the post from my angular application i can clearly see in the console that the content-type is correct and that the request payload consists out of 2 different parts named seedImage and seedDetails. Here are 2 screenshots illustrating this:

Request headers:

[image]

Request payload:

[image]

Yet when the request arrivés at my spring boot application it throws this exception.

```
2018-07-07 12:18:24.061 DEBUG 25956 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : Failed to resolve argument 0 of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile'

org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'seedImage' is not present
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:193) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:109) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:158) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) [spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) [spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) [spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) [spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) [spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at JwtComponents.JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter.java:64) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161]
```

This is my controller:

```
private Status createSeed(@RequestPart("seedImage") MultipartFile seedImage, @RequestPart("seedDetails") CreateSeedDTO createSeedDTO){ 
    logger.info(createSeedDTO.toString());
    User author = userDao.findByUserName(createSeedDTO.getAuthor()).orElseGet(null);
    if(author == null)
        return new Status(false,"User " + createSeedDTO.getAuthor() + " is unknown to the database.");
    else {
        SeedRecord seedRecord = new SeedRecord(createSeedDTO);
        seedRecord.setAuthor(author);
        return seedCalendarService.createNewSeedRecord(seedRecord);
    }
}
```

I already tried changing @RequestPart with @RequestParam but that has no effect.

I am trying to make this work following the examples of Craig walls his book Spring in action fourth edition. In his book he says you need to make a few configurations like so:

Webappinitializer config:

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration){
        registration.setMultipartConfig(new MultipartConfigElement("/tmp/images/uploads", 3145728, 4194304, 0));

    }
}
```

In the Java configuration class you put:

```
@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() throws IOException{
    return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
}
```

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong? I don't think the problem lies with the request coming from the angular application because everything in the request seems to look fine.

Comment: i've found out that it partially works when i remove the `@EnableWebMvc` from my WebConfig java configuration file and when i replace `MultipartFile` with `Part` file. However, The contenttype comes out null, and so thus the getSubmittedFileName, size is less then the actual size, so i really don't understand what is going on.

Comment: also, i get an error back as a response {"timestamp":1530965845957,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/api/seed/create"}

Comment: using HttpServletRequest as an alternative doesn't work either, nor does the use of CommonsMultipartFile.

Answer (score 0):

MutipartFile is an interface, Commonly Client will send or upload a file , it will be sent to server as in the form of mutipart request.

Click [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50560799/how-can-i-accept-multiple-multipart-files-in-my-spring-mvc-rest-controller/50602032#50602032) You Can Find Better Explanation. if it helps please vote.

Comment: this isn't helping sorry... I know very well what a MultipartFile is, i just keep getting the error that one of the MultiPart names cannot be found. If i remove the image part from the request, both clientside and serverside it will give the same error about seedDetails.. It sort of works when i remove @EnableWebMvc and replace MultipartFile with Part like i mentioned. But then the filename is null

Comment: right now i dropped the Multi part approach in favor of just sending the image as a base64 hash...

Comment: click here[https://walkintoknow.blogspot.com/2018/05/convert-image-to-base64-string-and.html]