# Spring Boot + Angular - MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I'm having an issue using Angular 9 with Spring Boot for a simple application that uploads files along with data from the UI, in the same request. Until I've implemented security with basic authentication, everything worked just fine. Now, after I'm logged in and want to upload data, I get the following error:

> `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request
>   is not a multipart request`

with the headers set up to `Content-Type: 'multipart/form-data'` and the Spring Controller using MultipartFile. The strange thing is that the GET request works well, with the exception it's content type is `application/json`. If I'm disabling the http-interceptor, the error becomes `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/pacients' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`. I've also tried every workaround for handling CORS, both Angular and Spring related, with no success.

Angular component for uploading the file:

```
pacient: Pacient;
pacientForm: FormGroup = new PacientCreateFormBuilder().build();
submitPromise: Promise<Pacient>;

onSubmit() {
    if(this.pacientForm.valid) {
      const formData: FormData = new FormData();
      formData.append('pacientFile', <File>this.pacientForm.value.pacientFile);
      formData.append('newPacient', new Blob([JSON.stringify(this.pacientForm.value)], {type: "application/json"}));

      this.submitPromise = this.pacientCreateService.save(formData);
    } else {
      ValidationUtils.markFormAsDirty(this.pacientForm);
    }
  }
```

Angular service for upload:

```
public save(formData: FormData) {
    var headers = new HttpHeaders(
      {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Authorization': `Basic ${window.btoa(this.authService.username + ":" + this.authService.password)}`
      }
    );

    return this.httpClient.post<Pacient>("http://localhost:8080/pacient", formData, {headers: headers})
      .toPromise();
  }
```

Angular authentication service:

```
authenticate(username: String, password: String) {
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:8080/auth`, {
      headers: { authorization: this.createBasicAuthToken(username, password) }}).pipe(map((res) => {
      this.username = username;
      this.password = password;
      this.registerInSession(username, password);
    }));
  }

  createBasicAuthToken(username: String, password: String) {
    return 'Basic ' + window.btoa(username + ":" + password);
  }

  registerInSession(username, password) {
    sessionStorage.setItem(this.SESSION_KEY, username);
  }
```

Angular http-interceptor:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (this.authService.isUserLoggedin() && req.url.indexOf('basicauth') === -1) {
      const request = req.clone({
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Basic ${window.btoa(this.authService.username + ":" + this.authService.password)}`
        })
      });
      return next.handle(request);
    }

    return next.handle(req);
  }
```

Spring Security config:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new StandardPasswordEncoder();

        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("admin")
                .password("admin")
                .roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().
                disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
```

Spring Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/pacient")
    public Pacient create(@RequestPart("pacientFile") MultipartFile pacientFile, @RequestPart("newPacient") PacientDTO pacientDTO)
```

**EDIT:** If I'm using `@PostMapping(value = "/pacient", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})` in the Controller, the error is changing and appears only on browser's console and sais

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/pacient' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

In order to get past it, I updated the Controller with `@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:4200"})`, added the following fields to the headers from service

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': `Content-Type`,
'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': `POST`,
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': `*`
```

and also created a proxy.conf.json file with

```
{
  "/": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

and added it to package.json, to start with `"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"` and added CORS configuration in my Spring Security config class

```
@Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource()
    {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

but still no luck...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including Controller code, any web-related config code etc.

Comment: Yes, just did it.

Comment: I'd like to see the code that creates/assembles the FormData. Something is calling your save() method, but I don't see it. I wonder if you're adding the 2 parts mentioned in the Controller (pacientFile, newPacient) to the FormData? I also don't see an `@Consumes` annotation on the controller, e.g. `@PostMapping(consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})`.

Comment: I updated the post with the uploading component which calls the service. One thing to notice, I tried to use @Consumes annotation, and now the error has changed and appears only on browser's console, not in terminal. It sais: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/pacient' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Re. example code: You've still not made it simple enough to run your code. E.g. Pacient, PacientCreateFormBuilder is missing. How I usually approach this: 1) Copy+paste Angular and/or Spring Boot project folders to new folders. 2) Launch projects from those folders. 3) Remove as much content as possible while leaving original functionality untouched so that the error can be reproduced. 4) Anonymize (remove sensitive info etc.) Basically, I want to be able to copy-paste your classes into my IDE and have it running. That way, I can better assist you.

Comment: Re. CORS: Tricky topic. Please try to understand 1) [CORS itself, the concept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) 2) [How to configure it with Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-cors). Please try to debug CorsFilter and CorsProcessor classes in the backend to gain further understanding.

Comment: I ran into the same problem about 2 years ago. My solution was to simply not use multipart and save the files as base64 instead, im sure thats not the answer you're looking for but its an alternative approach that you might be interested in. Heres my stackoverflow question describing the same problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51222363/spring-controller-cannot-read-image-file-from-multipart-form-data-post-request

Comment: Just check in browser console how request looks like.

Comment: Antoniossss, the browser's (Google Chrome) console doesn't show any request from me at this point.

@MonopoleMagnet I'll put the files for you, just tell me how do you want to have them sent.

Comment: If there's only a few more files left to make this a complete example, I recommend posting them here, otherwise try posting the frontend on Stackblitz or use GitHub repos or Pastebin... there's many possibilities

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this issue myself and it was a really dumb error on my end but I thought I should share in case someone made the same mistake. I had just moved the file over to my VM and my user account did not have access to the file... Once I changed the permissions to the file, it worked as expected.